# How can I add an info button in OSX today extension?

Tags: macos, swift, today-extension

I am looking for a way to add an "info" button on the top bar of a today extension. Just like the ones Apple uses in its own extensions in OSX. I have tried looking for ways to implement it but I can't seem to find anything.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, I finally found the solution:

You have to implement the following methods :

```
   //func widgetAllowsEditing() -> Bool {
   //     return true
   // }

    var widgetAllowsEditing: Bool {
        return true
    }
    func widgetDidBeginEditing() {

     // do your stuff

    }

    func widgetDidEndEditing() {

      // do your stuff

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the init `buttonWithType`.

```
//Light
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.InfoLight)

//Dark
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.InfoDark)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I add it to the top bar, right of the extension name ?

Comment: The question is about OS X, so NSButton needs to be used instead of UIButton.